# Run a vim formatter conditionally

Tags: vim, vi

I have a callback setup-ed that auto-formats the code automatically after saving the buffer (depending on the file type). I'd like to avoid this behavior for very long files. Is it possible to make `:w` behave the same as `:noa w`, when the file is longer than N lines?

Answer (score 2):

A direct implementation of your requirement would be by mapping `:w`. Through the use of `:help map-expr`, you can dynamically react to conditions (here: the number of lines in the buffer):

```
:nnoremap <expr> :w ':' . (line('$') >= 1000 ? 'noa ' : '') . 'w'
```

Note that there are more robust approaches for overriding built-in Ex commands. (For example [cmdalias.vim - Create aliases for Vim commands](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=746).)

#### Recommended alternative

The advantage of the mapping is that you directly see what effect it has (though you have to remember what effects `:noautocmd` has here), and you can influence / override it easily.

However, it won't work with mappings or plugins that invoke `:update` directly. I would prefer to modify the callback setup instead. You probably have something like

```
:autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> call AutoFormat()
```

I would introduce a boolean flag that guards this:

```
:autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> if exists('b:AutoFormat') && b:AutoFormat | call AutoFormat() | endif
```

And then setup a hook that initializes it:

```
:autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> if ! exists('b:AutoFormat') | let b:AutoFormat = (line('$') < 1000) | endif
```

This way, you see whether auto-formatting is enabled (you can even put `b:AutoFormat` into your statusline), and you can tweak the behavior by manipulating the flag:

```
:let b:AutoFormat = 0   " Turn off auto-formatting even though the buffer is small.
:let b:AutoFormat = 1   " Force auto-formatting even though it's a large buffer.
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. The link to cmdalias is broken (perhaps temporarily).

Comment: Yes, `vim.org` apparently currently undergoes a datacenter migration.